# Plotting Cook's Distance Lines

Tags: python, scatterplot, cooks-distance

I've currently created a plot using Python showing leverage vs residuals of some data. I want to plot Cook's Distance lines like shown in Case 2.

[image]

How would I go ahead with this?

Comment: You can get it directly from the relationship between Cook's distance, leverage and squared standardized residual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cook's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook's_distance): ${\displaystyle D_{i}={\frac {e_{i}^{2}}{s^{2}p}}\left[{\frac {h_{i}}{(1-h_{i})^{2}}}\right],}$ ($p$ is the column dimension of $X$)

[Leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)#Linear_regression_model): $h_{i}$

The version of standardized residual used in the plot is: $\frac{e_i}{s\sqrt{1 - h_i}}$
(well, it also uses weights if they're present; I presume weights are a non-issue for you - i.e. all 1 - since you didn't mention them)

Here's the piece of code in plot.lm that's computing the standardized residual:

```
        rsp <- dropInf(r.w/(s * sqrt(1 - hii)), hii)
```

(`r.w` having previously been computed from the raw residual by multiplying by the square root of weight)

Note therefore that if we call that standardized residual $r_i$ then $pD_i = r_i^2 h_i/(1-h_i)$. If you draw lines for $D=1$ and $D=0.5$, it's easy to see where they should go on a plot of $r$ vs $h$, by simple rearrangement of that formula.

Comment: What is the value of p?

Comment: As stated in the link on the line it's first mentioned, the number of columns in the design matrix $X$. I have edited to make it explicit.